# Is there a contain's method?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I know there's a method contain(), it looks like this:

```
Dim arr() as string = {"apple","banana","orange"}
For each fruit in arr
 If fruit.contains("app") Then
  Return True
 End If
Next
```

It will return true because "apple" contains letter "a". This is not what I want. I want it to return true only when "apple" contains the whole word "app". Is there any method or function to do this?

Comment: No it doesn't. It returns true because it matches on the word "app".  If it was matching on the letter "a" then for "banana" it would also return true.  Which it won't. Because god made it that way.

Comment: You are getting confuzzled by the String.Contains(Char) method.  It is an extension method, provided by System.Linq.  You are actually using String.Contains(String).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"apple" does in fact contain the whole word "app", so Contains() is still probably your best bet.

From MSDN:

> String.Contains Method   Returns a
>   value indicating whether the specified
>   String object occurs within this
>   string.

Here is the link to it with samples.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
If fruit.IndexOf("app") <> -1 Then
  Return True
End If
```

Comment: This is not a wrong answer, but seriously Contains is simpler to use and the intent is more clear. And Contains is NOT broken even though Cobold seems to think so.

Comment: @Meta-Knight : Correct, the documentation of Contains method says exactly what Cobold wants it to be.